# Call direct function in codeigniter on baseurl

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I am newbie to codeigniter.my problem is let suppose my baseurl is

```
www.xyz.com
```

Now I have function like this

```
class Front extends MY_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->__front_template('index');
    }
    public function about()
    {
        $this->__front_template('about-us');
    }
```

Now if I have to call about I call like

```
www.xyz.com/front/about
```

But I need to call like

```
www.xyz.com/about
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: add `$route['about'] = 'front/about';`
to your `routes.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use codeigniter **[URI routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)**

Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string and its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a URI normally follow this pattern:

Codeigniter URL Work as

```
example.com/class/function/id/
```

So you must route for this type. in `application/config/routes.php` add code like

```
$route['about'] = 'Front/about';
```

it works .!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `about` directly as per your architecture, because of the following reason.

**In CodeIgniter** we have URL divided as:
`http://www.example.com/controller_name/function_name`

If the function you are trying to call is `index` function that above can be written as: `http://www.example.com/controller_name/`

So, in order to call `about` directly you need to create a separate controller for it with the name `about` and you can write about code in `index` function. And your requirement will be fulfilled.

There are other complex ways to, but as you have mentioned you are **newbie**. so this will be best.

If you want a more efficient way, look at the documentation:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html